# What characters are equivalent in utf8_general_ci?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation

Obviously, uppercase and lowercase letters are considered equivalent. But does this apply only to Latin characters or more alphabets? Greek, etc?

Which accented letters are considered equivalent? In German collations you get `ü` equal to `u` or `ue` depending which one you use. Are there such things in `utf8_general_ci`?

And just how far does the equivalence go? The hiragana `ね` and katakana `ネ` both represent the same syllable, so do they count as equivalent in the collation?

I can't seem to find any information on this, which is strange considering how important it should be for things like unique keys...

Answer (score 0):

As you can find [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,187048,188748),  "it just removes all accents and then converts to upper case".

If you want to not check this, just use utf8_unicode_ci - it doesn't do these things and it's also faster. So, if you don't need it, don't use it!

And those Japanese... I really don't know. But it's easy to check...

Source: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,187048,188748